# What is the best way to pass list to another class for iteration

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm creating a ShapeList class for an ArrayList, and then I want to pass this list to ShapeDrawer class (that I'm instantiating in the ShapeList constructor) so it can be iterated over in ShapeDrawer class. Now, in the ShapeDrawer class constructor should the type expected be List or ShapeList? If I do type List then i can't use the ShapeList methods, if I make it type ShapeList, then Eclipse says to change ShapeDrawer constructor to List... I want to pass this list to other classes as well but have the same problem. Thanks very much for your help!!

```java
public class ShapeList implements Iterator{ 

    List<ShapeConfigPair> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ShapeList(PaintCanvas canvas, ShapeConfigPair activeShape) 
    {
        // ...
        ShapeDrawer shapeDrawer = new ShapeDrawer(canvas, shapeList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, of course it does, ShapeList doesn't implement List in any way. If you want to pass ShapeList to ShapeDrawer, then you should probably add it to constructor and then call new ShapeDrawer(canvas, this).

Answer (score 0):

It should be list, and you should cast it to a ShapeDrawer.

Answer (score 0):

The `ShapeDrawer` constructor should be List

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand what `implements Iterator` means in your class declaration, and it's not clear what your question really is.

One source of confusion is that you've defined a class, `ShapeList`, which has an instance variable named `shapeList` but which is of type `ArrayList`. You're passing the ArrayList to the constructor of `ShapeDrawer` but it sounds like what you want to be able to do in ShapeDrawer is to call methods on the `ShapeList` object that *holds* the ArrayList. So, instead of passing the ArrayList, you should probably be passing `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should extend `AbstractList<ShapeConfigPair>`. It's very easy, beacuse there's not a lo of things to do. Then you can pass that as a List with no problems.

Iterator is not designed to be the main class holding the data, it's rather meant to be used as a temporary adapter to go over a collection.